# Odoo: Model based on a SQL view to take a dynamic input from user

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I've created a model based on a sql view, but i want the query to take a dynamic input from the user, like a if i want to know the balance of the safe within a period that the user specifies, and when the user enter a date the query takes that input and retrieves the data based on this input, is that possible cause i've been searching for a solution

code example:

```
class SafeReportView(models.Model):
    _name = "ys.safe.report.3"
    _auto = False
    sub_account_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="ys.sub.account", string="Sub Account")
    date = fields.Date(string="Date", default=fields.Date.today)
    date1 = fields.Date(string="Start Date", default=fields.Date.today)
    date2 = fields.Date(string="End Date", default=fields.Date.today)
    debit = fields.Float(string="Debit")
    credit = fields.Float(string="Credit")
    balance = fields.Float(string="Balance")

def init(self):
        """ Event Question main report """
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'ys_safe_report_3')
        self._cr.execute(""" CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ys_safe_report_3 AS (
select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS id, 
ysa.id as sub_account_id, 
ysal.debit as debit, 
ysal.credit as credit, 
ysal.balance as balance, 
ysal.date as date, 
from ys_sub_account_line ysal 
inner join ys_sub_account ysa 
on ysal.sub_account_id = ysa.id 
inner join ys_transaction yt 
on ysal.transaction_id = yt.id
where ysa.name like 'Safe - %' and  ysal.date >= '%s' and ysal.date <= '%s'
""" % (self.date1, self.date2))
```

Comment: Just create a "plain" view with all data. You don't need `date1` and `date2` fields. Implement your model client views (for example pivot). The search functionality in the odoo client (lots of report examples to find) can then be used by users to filter on field `date`.

Comment: Example sales order report (Odoo 14): [python code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9b23864027bc24032993833f213395cb45fe86bb/addons/sale/report/sale_report.py), [views](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9b23864027bc24032993833f213395cb45fe86bb/addons/sale/report/sale_report_views.xml).

Comment: the thing is i don't wanna filter the data, i want it to retrieve data based on my selection, for example the total sales varies according to the period chosen by the user

Comment: A filter is like a selection by the user, isn't it?

Comment: but the filter only narrows down the selection of an already retrieved data that do not change its value based on that filter, what i need to do is that a user gives an input, and based on  that input the query retrieves the data, i.e. the query takes a variable that's given by the user

Comment: I did understand what you want, but why do you want to "filter" on the query instead of just "filter" in the web client? The second one is way more easier.

Comment: because it won't be possible to get something like the average of some field over a user defined period of time, or the total sales over a certain period etc

Comment: If the report fields are defined correctly it will ofcourse get the right aggregations. Another example for that: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9b23864027bc24032993833f213395cb45fe86bb/addons/project/report/project_report.py#L20-L25

Comment: won't give the desired result, lets assume the query calculates the total sales and average selling price for each product without specifying a date in the where clause. filtering the data and specifying a date in the filter wouldn't change the values of the total sales or the average selling price, though in reality they do change depending on the period

Comment: That's why you break the data down to smaller pieces. Because you want to allow user later to search/filter/aggregate on dates, perhaps the smallest point to watch for is the `date` column. Just remove the `where` clause and select also the `ysa.name` as name field and Odoo will probably do the rest ;-)

Comment: but can you please explain how breaking down the data into smaller pieces would make any difference?

Comment: You have everything already. Remove the where clause and also remove `date1` and `date2`. Also manage to set default values in the query not on odoo field definitions, because reports are "readonly" anyway. Add a pivot view and then look into it. You should be able to search/filter for date range in the pivot search bar.